# Why are the InspectorControls not appearing when creating a block

Tags: wordpress

Gutenberg v1.9.1

In the following block I have set the InspectorControls to appear but nothing shows up under the Block settings in the UI.

I have added InspectorControls from wp.blocks.

I then use the Inspector controls using:

```js
props.focus && (
  <InspectorControls key="inspector">
    <PanelBody title={ __( 'Direction Settings' ) }>
      <ToggleControl
        label={ __( 'Image on right' ) }
        checked={ 'right' === attributes.direction }
        onChange={ toggleDirection }
      />
    </PanelBody>
  </InspectorControls>
),
```

Here is a gist:  https://gist.github.com/belcherj/b9007c75af68ab8b3ccc06ab9a5f43b6

UPDATE: Here is an updated gist with everything working: https://gist.github.com/belcherj/27c2a1ef532ebf8e8a9f333c12d5bc97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your complete Gist snippet, you're not returning an array of elements from `save`, you're returning a parenthesis-wrapped return result, which evaluates to the last item.

You'd want to update the following line from a parenthesis to a square bracket (and likewise for the closing bracket):

https://gist.github.com/belcherj/b9007c75af68ab8b3ccc06ab9a5f43b6#file-gistfile1-txt-L74